# React, Redux Application - Best pattern for passing initial state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to build a reusable Grid component with React & Redux. Each sub component (Filters, Paginator, Sorters etc) requires initial configuration or initial state. Currently I am setting the configuration in the reducer as initial state. Below is an example of column definitions reducer

```
import { Map, OrderedMap } from 'immutable'

let initialState = OrderedMap({
    'name': Map({ id: 'name', description: 'Name'}),
    'job': Map({ id: 'job', description: 'Job Title'}),
    'salary': Map({ id: 'salary', description: 'Salary'}),
    'phone': Map({ id: 'phone', description: 'Phone'}),
    'state':  Map({ id: 'state', description: 'State'}),
    'hiredate' : Map({id: 'hiredate', description: 'Date Hired'})
});

let columnDefinitionsReducer = (namespace) => (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default columnDefinitionsReducer;
```

Grid component is connected to store and builds columns based on the state in the store.

In order to make the grid reusable so that different components can pass in different column definitions, what is the best pattern to follow. Where do I need to keep this configuration?

Comment: i like to export an object of `initialState` where i can see the entire state shape. the only initial state that i write inside the reducer's file is the state that belongs to reducers that i'm not using in my components directly, they are only part of the reducer composition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a configuration object for the grid and passing it as a parameter to reducers. I am not sure if this is the best way, but it serves my purpose

Here is the structure

**Config Object**

```
let employeeConfig = {
    namespace: 'employees',
    columndefs: OrderedMap({
        'name': Map({ id: 'name', description: 'Name'}),
        'job': Map({ id: 'job', description: 'Job Title'}),
        'salary': Map({ id: 'salary', description: 'Salary'}),
        'phone': Map({ id: 'phone', description: 'Phone'}),
        'state':  Map({ id: 'state', description: 'State'}),
        'hiredate' : Map({id: 'hiredate', description: 'Date Hired'})
    }),
    filters: OrderedMap({
        'name': Map({ id: 'name', hint: 'Search by name', value: '', maxValue: '', type: 'text' }),
        'job': Map({ id: 'job', hint: 'Search by job title', value: '', maxValue: '', type: 'text' }),
        'state':  Map({ id: 'state', hint: 'Search by state', value: '', maxValue: '', type: 'text' }),
        'salary':  Map({ id: 'salary', hint: 'Salary', value: '', maxValue: '', type: 'range' }),
        'hiredate':  Map({ id: 'hiredate', hint: 'Hired Date', value: '', maxValue: '', type: 'date-range' })
    }),
    perPage: 10,
    defaultSort: 'id'
}
export default employeeConfig;
```

**Root Reducer**

```
 import employeeConfig from '../components/employees/employee_config'

const employeesReducer = combineReducers({
    currentPage : currentPageReducer(employeeConfig.namespace, 1),
    itemProperties : itemPropertiesReducer(employeeConfig.namespace, employeeConfig.columndefs),       
    itemsPerPage : perPageReducer(employeeConfig.namespace, employeeConfig.perPage),
    sortingProperty : sortReducer(employeeConfig.namespace, employeeConfig.defaultSort),
    filters : filtersReducer(employeeConfig.namespace, employeeConfig.filters)
});
```

**Reducer**

```
 let itemsPerPage = (namespace, config) => (state = config, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case `${namespace}/${UPDATE_PER_PAGE}`:
            return action.payload
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default itemsPerPage;
```